# How to get user's birthday from python-social-auth

Tags: django, python-social-auth

so I've set up my Django app, and I want to get birthday from Facebook and save it somewhere in the pipeline. I did request scope:

`SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email','user_birthday']`

Most answers to similar question use the `response` dict returned by Facebook. However, when I print it, I have this:

```
{
'id': .., 
'expires': .., 
'name': .., 
'granted_scopes': ['user_birthday', 'email', 'public_profile'], 
'access_token': ..
}
```

How do I get the actual birthday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have the access token, you can use it to send a get request:

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/%d?fields=birthday' % user_id
parameters = {'access_token': TOKEN}
r = requests.get(url, params = parameters)
result = json.loads(r.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you use `access_token` to communicate with FB Graph API. One of the ways to do it is to send a request manually, like [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49654381/4507367) says. However, the way I ended up doing it was with [facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) library which is easier on the eyes:

```
from facepy import GraphAPI

def work_with_response(response, *args, **kwargs):
    graph = GraphAPI(response['access_token'])
    fb_data = graph.get('me?fields=birthday')
    date = fb_data['birthday']
```